# Initialize IEnumerable<int> as optional parameter

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have an optional parameter of type `IEnumerable<int>` in my C# method. Can I initialize it with anything but `null`, e.g. a fixed list of values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You can only have compile time constants. You can assign in to null and then

```
void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<int> list = null)
{
    if(list == null)
        list = new List<int>{1,2,3};
}
```

Next code snippet is take from well-known `C# in Depth` book by `Jon Skeet`. Page 371. He suggest to use null as kind of `not set` indicator for parameters, that may have meaningful default values.

```
static void AppendTimestamp(string filename,
                            string message,
                            Encoding encoding = null,
                            DateTime? timestamp = null)
{
     Encoding realEncoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
     DateTime realTimestamp = timestamp ?? DateTime.Now;
     using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true, realEncoding))
     {
         writer.WriteLine("{0:s}: {1}", realTimestamp, message);
     }
}
```

Usage

```
AppendTimestamp("utf8.txt", "First message");
AppendTimestamp("ascii.txt", "ASCII", Encoding.ASCII);
AppendTimestamp("utf8.txt", "Message in the future", null, new DateTime(2030, 1, 1));
```

Comment: The really awesome side effect of this pattern is that you don't encounter the issue with call-site binding of default params if you are exposing those through some class library, since this allows you to modify the defaults and have them take effect when the library is updated.  Thus avoiding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/664691/84206

Answer (score 4):

No - default parameters must be compile-time constants.

Your best bet is to overload the method. Alternatively, set the default value to null and inside your method detect a null and turn it into the list you want.

Answer (score 4):

How about making its default value as null, and within the method

```
numbers = numbers ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

or

```
numbers = numbers ?? new []{ 1, 2, 3}.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you need a compile time constant.

But you could use an overload as work around:

```
public void Foo(int arg1)
{
      Foo(arg1, new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}

public void Foo(int arg1, IEnumerable<int> arg2)
{
      // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well since you need compile time constants you would have to set it to `null`

but then you can do the following in your method

```
 list = list ?? new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the accepted answer forever, but I just had a brainstorm, and I think it would be interesting to share.

Using the semantics of `default()` with a `struct`, you can do this:

```
public readonly struct EmptyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
         return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// ...elsewhere...

public void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> bar = default(EmptyEnumerable<T>))
{
}
```

The reason this works is because the `default` of a struct is not `null`, but is an instance of the struct as if it was called with the default constructor.  Since `default` is determined at compile time, the compiler is happy with it, and it just works.

Of course, you can change the contents of `GetEnumerator` to return whatever you'd like, not just `Enumerable.Empty`, this is just my use-case.

**Disclaimer**

I do not actually use this in my code, for fear of issues caused by boxing.  I just wanted to post this as an interesting exploration of how C# works.  Maybe there's a way to solve the boxing issue, if I think of one, I'll come back here and update.

Comment: this doesnt work at all, it wont even compile. at least not with .net core 8. and you are also missing the return type in the GetEnumerator method.